# How to declare vector of object in c++?

Tags: c++

I receive the following error on declaring a vector of `Point` in the code shown (see reference to class template instantiation `std::vector<Point,std::allocator<Point>>` being compiled):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error C2558   class 'Point': no copy constructor available or copy
> constructor is declared 'explicit'    AI assignment 1 C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xmemory   671

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int dx, dy, sx, sy;

class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    float g;
    float h;

    Point()
    {}
    Point(int s, int d)
    {
        x = s;
        y = d;
        h = pow(pow(x - dx, 2) + pow(y - dy, 2), 1 / 2);

    }
    Point(Point &p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        g = p.g;
        h = p.h;
    }

    bool operator == (Point p)
    {
        if (p.x == x && p.y == y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

};

class RoutePlaner
{
    vector<vector<char>>grid;
    int mapsize;
    Point start;
    Point destination;
    int no_of_obstacles;
    vector<Point> obstacles;

    void generate_random_obstacles(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            int k = rand() % mapsize;
            int j = rand() % mapsize;
            Point p(i, j);
            grid[j][k] = 'X';
            obstacles.push_back(p);
        }
    }
    
public:
    RoutePlaner(int m, Point s, Point d, int no)
    {
        mapsize = m;
        start = s;
        destination = d;
        no_of_obstacles = no;

        vector<char> vec(mapsize, '.');
        for (int i = 0; i < mapsize; i++)
        {
            grid.push_back(vec);
        }

        //Setting start and destination
        grid[start.x][start.y] = 'S';
        grid[destination.x][destination.y] = 'D';

        // setting obstacles
        generate_random_obstacles(no_of_obstacles);


    }
};

int main()
{

}
```

How should I declare a vector of class objects? How do I resolve the error?

Comment: Not sure if that causes the problem, but a copy-ctor should take it's parameter by const reference.

Comment: you made constant `Point`s non-copyable, because `Point(Point &p)` only accepts non-const `Point`s. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: fwiw, the lesson to learn here is: make everything `const` by default, only non-const when it needs to be modified.

Answer (score 3):

You need your [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) for the `Point` class to conform to what `std::vector` (and many other aspects of the STL and C++ language) expects: that means its argument should be a `const` reference:

```cpp
    Point(const Point& p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        g = p.g;
        h = p.h;
    }
```

Although, in your case, as pointed out in the [comment by M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67242905/how-to-declare-vector-of-object-in-c/67242963?noredirect=1#comment118857075_67242963), the compiler-generated copy constructor will do *exactly* the same job as yours, so you can just omit your 'explicit' version. Furthermore, if you *do* declare your own copy constructor, you should also declare a destructor and an assignment operator, in order to follow to "[Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)." (Or you can 'meet halfway' by explicitly declaring the default copy constructor: `Point(const Point& p) = default;`.)

---

Note, also, that you can simplify your `operator ==` function: whenever you have code of the form, `if (x) return true; else return false;` you should consider using just `return (x);`, like this:

```cpp
    bool operator == (Point p) {
        return (p.x == x && p.y == y);
    }
```

Comment: A better solution would be to remove this function from the code and allow the implicitly generated copy constructor. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: @M.M Good point - I was more concerned with a 'quick correction'. I have incorporated your comment into the answer, making it (hopefully) a better reference.